# Wix installer error 2878 when using three radiobuttons

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use wix toolset to create installer for WPF appilcation. When i want to use three radiobuttons, i get error :

> "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this
> package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code
> is 2878".

but when i use two radiobuttons everything is ok.
There is my code :

```
<UI>
    <Property Id="AppType" Value="False"/>
    <Dialog Id="PoolSettingsDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Application Pool Settings - [ProductName]" NoMinimize="yes">
        
    <Control Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="AppType" Id="AUTH" Width="144" Height="100" X="45" Y="100">
        <RadioButtonGroup Property="AppType">
            <RadioButton Text="!(loc.AppTypeDefault)" Height="15" Value="False" Width="150" X="0" Y="0" />
            <RadioButton Text="!(loc.AppTypeCallCenter)" Height="15" Value="False" Width="150" X="0" Y="15" />
            <RadioButton Text="!(loc.AppTypeFoodPoint)" Height="15" Value="True" Width="150" X="0" Y="30" />
        </RadioButtonGroup>
    </Control>
    </Dialog>
</UI>
```

Comment: The installer logs will tell you more about the error. I suspect that it is because the `Value ="False"` appears twice. Also: this question has nothing to do with C# and WPF; dont tag-spam, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value attributes of RadioButtons in a RadioButtonGroup must be distinct.
2xFalse is not, therefore the error.
I would go with Value=Default, CallCenter, FoodPoint.

Comment: Thanks , it works!!